# Android set webview content fit to width

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that loads a page with an image in it. I want this webview content to fit the width of the device. The webview itself fits to screen width but its content does not. Here is what i do:

```
bannerWV = new WebView(getContext());
bannerWV.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient());
bannerWV.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
bannerWV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
bannerWV.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
bannerWV.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

bannerWV.loadUrl("http://...");
feedsLV.addHeaderView(bannerWV);
```

In samsung galaxy s5, its content fits to width but in smaller width devices, it has a scroll and scrolls in the left-right direction. Also, if i remove setloadwithoverview, this time in smaller width devices i have a white space at the right side of the screen. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting image width to 100% solved the problem for me.

```
<img alt="..." rev="..." src="..." border="0" width="100%">
```

And for the white space at the right side of the screen, the following worked:

```
webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```